# putting variable from php into html

Tags: php

I've searched and i couldn't find my fault,
I want to display the `$content` inside my textarea. I've also tried to put it into the value attribute but that didn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$search = array('foo','bar','foobar');
$replace = array('f**','b**','f**b**');

if (isset($_POST['cencor']) &&! empty($_POST['cencor'])){
    $content = $_POST['cencor'];
}

?>
<form action="findstring.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="cencor" rows="10" cols="80"><?php echo $content ?></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You miss a semicolon after `$content` inside of your textarea?

Comment: To detect further errors, you should put your error reporting on. To do so add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to the beginning of your file, you can read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: It could be the "&&!".  Try  a space between the last ampersand and the exclamation and no space between the exclamation and the word "empty".  But overall error_reporting is probably what you want!  Helps me out a lot!

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here and the comment/answer about the missing semi-colon is wrong; it's perfectly valid, same thing for `&&! empty`. Why don't you show us what you're really wanting to do here, seeing those extra functions.

Comment: @Rsauxil The missing semi-colon is perfectly valid (syntax) since there are no further (PHP) instructions following it. Had there been a conditional statement used for it, then that would be a different story and it would be required.

Comment: Didn't know that, but on a side note, I still think it's cleaner if you add a semicolon; it's a good way of getting used to always using them, as you actually will need to add them in 95% of the cases.

Comment: @Rsauxil Oh, I agree with you there, I always close off mine, yet in what the OP posted for code, would be considered valid, *just saying*. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be getting the following error in your `<textarea>` as soon as the page is loaded:

`<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: content in <b>/path/to/file.php</b> on line <b>x</b><br />`

Yet you're not checking for errors.

What you need to do is to use a conditional statement inside it for the `$content` variable.

Sidenote: The missing semi-colon in there, is perfectly valid since there is no further (PHP) instructions being passed after it, so let's lose that misconception (in comments).

However, it would be needed if there was a conditional statement when using the following:

```
if(isset($content)){ echo $content }
```

and would fail because it's looking for an "end of statement" and throwing the following:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in...

- The semi-colon being an "end of statement" character.

It's unclear as to what you really want to do here with the arrays, so I won't be able to help you there.

Another sidenote:

`&&! empty` is valid, but for the sake of argument, I've made it more readable, `&& !empty`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$search = array('foo','bar','foobar');
$replace = array('f**','b**','f**b**');

if (isset($_POST['cencor']) && !empty($_POST['cencor'])){
    $content = $_POST['cencor'];
}

?>
<form action="findstring.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="cencor" rows="10" cols="80"><?php if(isset($content)){ echo $content; } ?></textarea><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

This conditional statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['cencor']) && !empty($_POST['cencor']))
```

can be cut down to merely:

```
if (!empty($_POST['cencor']))
```

There's no need to use `isset()`, as `!empty()` is quite enough.

On an added note:

In order to avoid an undefined variable notice, you could have done the following and assigning "nothing" to the `$content` variable, which is perfectly valid:

```
$search = array('foo','bar','foobar');
$replace = array('f**','b**','f**b**');

    if (isset($_POST['cencor']) &&! empty($_POST['cencor'])){

        $content = $_POST['cencor'];
    }

$content = "";
```

---

**Closing notes:**

If the goal here is to keep the value that was entered in the `<textarea>` for the duration of the browser's session and the user navigating throughout your site, then that is just what you need to use here, **sessions**.

- http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

*For example:*

PHP:

```
if(!empty($_POST['cencor'])){

    $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['cencor'];
    $_POST['cencor'] = $_SESSION['var'];

}
```

HTML:

```
<textarea name="cencor" rows="10" cols="80"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['var'])){ echo $_SESSION['var']; } ?></textarea>
```

NOTA: If this answer does not solve what it is you want to achieve, you will need to elaborate on your question.

Comment: @DarkBee *hehe*, that almost sounds like *"molto bene"*

Comment: Thanks for the information you've given. but i was trying to just be able to read the $_POST. The question wasn't clear enough sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @TristanKenis You're welcome. If the answer I've given helped or solved it, then consider accepting it. If that still doesn't resolve it, then the problem is in your machine/system/hosted service. What I posted works, as I don't post answers that don't work or have not been tested. ;-)

Comment: @TristanKenis You're welcome. and like I said earlier, give it the tick next to the answer like in the link I gave you above. This informs everyone that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may be tempted to post more answers.