# PHP - $_POST not working (Simple Code)

Tags: php

I want to echo the value of the `textarea`.

I've tried :

- Changing `method="POST"` to `method="post"`referring to `action="anotherpage.php"`
- Changing the name

The code seems to work correctly with `GET` request.
So i'm out of ideas.
**My Code**:

```
<?php    
if(isset($_POST["name"])){

    $test= $_POST["name"];
    echo $test;
}    
?>
<form action="welcome.php" method="POST">
    <textarea id="welcome1" name="name" cols="60" rows="6"></textarea>
    <br><br><input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: may i know the filename ?

Comment: `anotherpage.php` or `welcome.php` ?

Comment: the filename is welcome.php

Comment: show me both scripts live and I will help you...

Comment: Are you running this on a web server? There is nothing wrong with the code you've posted here.

Comment: no i'm running this local

Comment: @TristanKenis if this filename is welcome.php and if you are running with webserver (or even localhost) it should work perfectly

Comment: There is your problem. PHP requires a web server, even locally, to run. Install XAMPP or some other web server on your local machine.

Comment: i use phpstorm with php 5.6.20

Comment: i also use xamp to let the php file run

Comment: @JayBlanchard he is running in webserver only it seems he said _if i test this code with **get** it works_

Comment: Is the PHP file in XAMPP's htdoc directory?

Comment: Maybe @Thamilan, but I sense some confusion.

Comment: @JayBlanchard How could it work with get if not in the appropriate directory? How could he even display the form?

Comment: The form would display in any web browser because it isn't generated code.

Comment: Copied/Pasted your code in a `welcome.php` file on my test host and... no surprise, it works. So the truth is out there.

Comment: @JayBlanchard PHP would not be interpreted: OP would certainly have noticed that

Comment: @TristanKenis what do you actually get? Any error? What if you `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: Maybe @Arcesilas, but if running in an IDE it might not display. Like I said, I sense some confusion.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes is is in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\phpstorm

Comment: @JayBlanchard Please read complete question and all OP's comments: he is running XAMP. Don't assume he's so dumb.

Comment: What address are you putting in the browser @TristanKenis?

Comment: Never said dumb @Arcesilas. I said confused. Don't assume I haven't read the question.

Comment: :/ arf... always the same problem: giving information piece by piece. Soon, torture will be required to make sure we get all relevant information from askers.

Comment: @Arcesilas with the var_dump i get 'array(0) { } '

Comment: Such an extended discussion should not be necessary to understand what's going on.

Comment: @JayBlanchard http://localhost:63342/phpstorm/welcome.php i get this adress automatically  if i start it with phpstorm, i've also tried to test it with file:///C:/XAMPP/htdocs/phpstorm/welcome.php but that gives also no result

Comment: What if you remove the port number? XAMPP typically runs Apache on port 80

Comment: @JayBlanchard it works with port numer 80 thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help @TristanKenis

Comment: Right all the way throught then Jay Blanchard ... as usual! @Arcesilas

Comment: @JayBlanchard You shoudl have been a dentist, you are great at pulling teeth

Comment: The noise keeps me away from that @RiggsFolly!

Comment: Then the house went *Boom!* @JayBlanchard - Did you hear the *earth shattering Kaboom?*

Comment: How about you @RiggsFolly ? ^

Comment: LOL @Fred-ii- only after using the mod-u-lay-tor!

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's back-ordered at ACME, unfortunately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed I can see it on source code of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)

Comment: You also posted this http://stackoverflow.com/q/37333782/ and given answers (one was deleted) and mine's still there. So, what's up with that one? Gotten no feedback from that whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

XAMPP typically runs Apache on port 80 – Jay Blanchard
manually changing the default portnumber to 80 in phpstorm solves the issue.